# Multiprocessing inside subprocess in python

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

Lets say I have a python script A, which communicates with some proprietary software using its API, and this API does not allow multiprocessing/multithreading. In script A, there is a function (func) that can utilize multiprocessing for better efficiency. Since I cannot use multiprocessing in script A for func, I define another python script B with the func, and then i use subprocess.run() to spawn a subprocess to run this Script B.

Script A looks like as below

```
import subprocess

def main():
    py2output=subprocess.run(["python.exe","ScriptB.py"],capture_output=True).stdout
    print(py2output.decode('UTF-8'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and Script B looks like as below

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def do_something():
    print("Inside Do Something")
    print("Sleeping 2 sec...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Done Sleeping")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("In main")

    p1=multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2=multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The output I expected was

```
In main
Inside Do Something
Sleeping 2 sec...
Done Sleeping
Inside Do Something
Sleeping 2 sec...
Done Sleeping
```

The output i got was

```
Inside Do Something
Sleeping 2 sec...
Done Sleeping
Inside Do Something
Sleeping 2 sec...
Done Sleeping
In main
```

In the output main function(Script B) gets executed at the end ?? Could anybody explain what is happening in the above scripts ?

**EDIT** How I really communicate with the proprietary software:
So the proprietary software provides me with a .exe(soft.exe) file. So how I actually run is I open the cmd and type the following command,

```
path_of_the_proprietary_soft_exe\soft.exe path_to_the_script_A\ScriptA.py -args _additional_argurments_here
```

So you in a nutshell you could say that soft.exe, runs my ScriptA.py, which then, in turn, will use ScriptB.py to create multi processes.  Since soft.exe controls the main process(ScriptA.py) it does not lets me to spawn additional processes. I hope I was clear with this information.

Comment: ScriptA is not valid code, some mistakes with brackets. Could edit your post so the code is valid?

Comment: I don't quite get the constraint. If the API cannot be used concurrently, that shouldn't prevent the script from doing *other* tasks using concurrency (multiprocessing, threading, …). Are you sure you aren't trying to solve an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code shown: the output ``In main``, followed by *both* subprocesses pre-sleep, followed by *both* subprocesses post-sleep, as I would expect. Note that the ``print("In main")`` *must* execute before the subprocesses are even started.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was able to reproduce the issue when running the script normally. I tried debugging it with VS Code and the produces the expected output. Could it be something with times of threads?

Comment: @Tzane Hm, I was able to reproduce each multiprocess having its own output block, but the main print still comes first (and putting one at the end comes last). Adding ``time.asctime()`` to the prints shows that they are *created* at the correct time, but not captured. I *assume* it's due to buffering, which uses different defaults for tty and non-interactive callers.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I had added additional information on how I actually use the API methods and communicate with the proprietary software. Regarding the issue, I was able to reproduce the issue when I tried with the above Scripts in my VS Code. Hope this helps.